# row sorted column sorted matrix

Tags: python, c, algorithm, sorting, matrix

can anyone suggest an algorithm for generating a row sorted, column sorted 2-D matrix given a list of integers ?
What I mean is that all rows and all columns should be sorted, preferably in asc/desc order for the entire matrix.

What I came up with is that first sort the list of elements, start at 0,0 and then place the next element at 0,1 then 1,0 then 0,2 then 2,0 and so forth. When there is a limit breach for row/column, pick the next row/column and continue.

Examples of my algo- 
Elements are natural numbers starting from zero.

3 X 5 Matrix -

```
0        1      3   5   7 
2        6      9   11  13
4        8      10  12  14
```

5 X 7 Matrix -

```
0     1      3     5     7   9  11
2     10     13   15    17  19  21
4     12     18   23    24  26  28
6     14     20   25    29  30  32
8     16     22   27    31  33  34
```

Is this right ?
Can you propose an alternate algo and any code for that (Python/C) ?
Thanks in advance.

Edit - Preferably not using any other libraries in Python e.g. numpy etc. Is there a way to implement this with simple plain old python code ?

Answer (score 2):

Treat your 2x2 matrix as a single dimension array and sort that using `qsort()`.
Voila!

```
int arr[3][3];
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        arr[row][col] = row * 3 + col;
    }
}
qsort(arr[0], 9, sizeof (int), delta);
```

---

```
int delta(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return *aa - *bb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an `RxC` array, where `R ~ C` and `R>C`, it is clear that the task requires at least to sort all rows, taking an effort `O(R.C.Log(C))`. Compare this to the effort for a global sort `O(R.C.Log(R.C)) = O(R.C.Log(C))` and you see that it may not be really worth to try and find shortcuts, unless `R>>C`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks but rather than sorting all the elements and then constructing a matrix out of it, is there another way to do it ? I need this to solve this - http://www.hackerearth.com/adobe-hiring-challenge/algorithm/mind-palaces-3/ where I need to check an input array whether it's in the proper format and if not, reconstruct it.

Comment: You can implement a sort working in-place in the array with proper comparison and exchange functions. Quicksort would fit. If you hope to somehow map an algorithm to the array structure, you can sort every row independently, then finish with mergesort passes that operate on whole rows.

Comment: Next time, please state what you want from the beginning!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 2 for cicle into a for cicle:

an example:

```
int matrix[4][4]; //your matrix is a 4x4 in this example
int sum[]={0,0,0,0};

for(int index=0; index<=4; index++){
    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){  //here sum the row
        sum[index]+=matrix[index][i];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){  //here sum the column
        sum[index]+=matrix[i][index];
    }
}
```

at the end you will have sum of row&column A in sum[0], B in sum[1],...

Answer (score -1):

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: :D I understand that but I am looking for something a bit more complex so that I don't have to sort the list in the beginning. Any algo for that ? :)